# Blender 2.8 (python) - this line of code causes inexplicable fatal crash

Tags: python

This line of code worked fine until I dropped it into a function.  Now when it executes, blender shuts down without throwing an error:

```
bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport = True, write_still=True)
```

The error likely has nothing to do with the code, but maybe has tapped into an internal corruption within Blender?

Has anyone ever encountered this before?  Possible solutions?

Comment: Does rendering through the UI work properly (F12)? You can run Blender from the terminal with `--debug` to get error messages or on Windows `blender_debug_gpu.cmd` in Blender's install directory by double-clicking on it (this will create a log file).

Comment: how often is that line of code executed by the function you put it in?  ..instead of that line can you write `print('happens')` and see if it's executed perhaps more often than you realize?